# How does approximate median aggregation work in MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, analytics, aggregation

I'm trying to understand how approximate median aggregation works in hadoop, like how to exactly do the map and reduce. If you can give me a short example or point me to some other online resources/materials, it will be awesome!

My final goal is to make an approximate median aggregator in crunch. And thus I'm looking for a good algorithm/strategy (in details) that can do this aggregation in a distributive way.

Comment: Did you have a look at similar questions ? [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109514/computing-median-in-map-reduce) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968215/find-median-of-a-large-integer-set-using-mapreduce)

Comment: Please, add some more info, like what is exactly the thing that you need and what have you tried so far.